# Find a condition row by row

Tags: matlab

Consider the following example

```
disp('Tag1Number      Tag2number')
for i = 1:numel(T1starttime)
    indexPDfind = find(T1starttime(i)<T2starttime & T2endtime<T1endtime(i));
    if(~isempty(indexPDfind))
        fprintf(' %d              %d\n',i,indexPDfind.')
    end

end
```

Where `T1starttime` `T2starttime` `T1endtime` are tags of timestamps vectors , I am trying to find the tags T2 which are with in T1 tags , Initially I am trying to find the start time of tags T2 within each tag1 of T1 , The above code works fine , but the number of tags can be very high and I dont want to use a loop , Is there any function like `bsxfun()` which will go row by row to find the certain index

Comment: If you are serious about performance, consider whether you could actually use a more efficient algorithm rather than making the current one run faster. I don't have a full solution in mind for this, but I believe you may be able to reduce the computational complexity if you sort your inputs.

Comment: Actually the data has already been sorted , when I convert my tags into a table and through those tables i fetch this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with `bsxfun`, I believe the relevant functions are `gt` and `lt`.

This may speed up the calculation a bit, but for big inputs (where most can be gained) memory might become an issue.

However, for medium/small sizes, the main performance improve that you will get will not likely come from this. You currently do a print each time you find a result.

Printing 1 thing is horribly slow, make sure to store all your results and print them at the end in 1 time to get a proper speedup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I was just priting to see if I was getting the correct result In my orignal code I would not do it , your suggestion is pretty good however there is one problem with it that I have to apply seprate bsxfun() for checking both condition

Comment: what do you think of using arrayfun ?

Comment: @Umar For speed `bsxfun` should definitely win. If I recall correctly: `arrayfun` is a wrapper for a loop, whilst `bsxfun` tries to use memory to gain speed.